# Background images looks stretched in Iphone and ipad

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, ipad

I am currently working on a small project. which has a lot of full-screen background images.

http://app.mindmax.in:9080/1904/homepage.html
the images looks very stretched out in iPhone and ipad. It looks fine in other android phones.

http://app.mindmax.in:9080/1904/homepage.html

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the relevant code in here?

Comment: I will add screenshots now, project can be opened from link